# "Where is this used?" not showing Reports where the field is used in a converted version

Tags: metadata, fields, custom-reports, field-dependencies

I just hit this —which seems to be a bug— and need to find all the reports where a field is being used. Any tips other than retrieving the metadata and ctrl+f for it?

**edit**:
This is happening in an Org with multi-currency enabled, by *converted version* I mean the field added to the report as a column, is the calculated conversion of the original (currency) field.

Comment: any reason why retrieve and ctrl + F doesn't meet the need?

Comment: It does, I was hoping for a solution in the line of "set this config option on and it'll fix it". Also, the main intention of my post was to share the knowledge that the problem exists with the community, in case anyone else may have overlooked it. I could not find any reference to it here or in the broader web.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what kind of answer you're looking for. In terms of the bug, can you be more specific? What do you mean by "used in a converted version"? That way, someone else can replicate it and then possibly suggest a way to fix it.

Comment: Absolutely, will improve the issue's description to be more specific. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a workaround to this as it's all out of "our" hands. If you can put in a support case, I'd be interested in if this is a "bug" or just not properly [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_references.htm&type=5) as a gap in functionality.

I replicated the same behavior. While looking at the metadata in the report that wasn't flagged, I can see Salesforce appends a `.CONVERT` to the field. I presume this throws it off from actually matching

```
<columns>
   <aggregateTypes>Sum</aggregateTypes>
   <field>Opportunity.Your_Custom_Field__c.CONVERT</field>
</columns
```

I assume the button is just using the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_api_metadatacomponentdependency_beta.htm) as it's mentioned in this [workaround](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KST3QAO) concerning the button not working. You can see the same behavior in the query in Dev Console using the Tooling API and the custom field ID (which you can get from the URL when on the custom field page). The reports with a converted version of the field fail to show there as well.

Retrieve metadata and CTRL + F will still work in this scenario and is probably your best (and potentially only) option here. A very weak workaround going forward is to try to communicate to always include both the field and "converted" field in reports together. Doesn't help you in this case with existing reports, however.